# Amazon EC2 instance pinging but django server is not accessible from outside

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have my django application on ec2 instance. I am able run it on ec2 instance on localhost:8000. When I try to access that django application from outside of that ec2 instance, it doesn't show me "this site can't be reached". **It is pinging**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see that you are running on localhost so it is not accessible from outside. Try running your server with command below and try to access with your server ip.

```
$ python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Go to your http://server-ip:8000

Comment: Check in the security group that port 8000 is open and can be accessed through your ip

Answer (score 0):

try to do telnet on that server on port 8000 and see if it works.

did u open port 8000 from security groups or not ! Most probably it is this issue.

Comment: sorry, but telnet did not work. and we tried your second solution with changing the port to 8080 and adding it to security group.  but it still not working man